# Calculate matrix cell value from it's indices

Tags: algorithm, matrix

If I want to fill a matrix with numbers with the following format (notice the sequence of numbers from [1-25] )

```
1 | 3 | 6 | 10 | 15
2 | 5 | 9 | 14 | 19 
4 | 8 | 13| 18 | 22
7 | 12| 17| 21 | 24
11| 16| 20| 23 | 25
```

my question is: is there any way to calculate cell value from it's indices without looping through all matrix cells to destination cell ?

ex : given i=2 , j=2 (calculate cell value from i & j => 13)

why do I need this? In my case I have large matrices of large sizes, the example above is for demonstration purpose only.

Comment: yes, if possible @n.m

Comment: Draw some ascending diagonals in the matrix. Say 2 and 3 are on an ascending diagonal. 11 12 13 14 15 are on another ascending diagonal. Given a pair of indices, can you calculate the number of the ascending diagonal that passes through that cell? What about the number of the cell within that diagonal? How many numbers are on all diagonals with numbers smaller than this one?

Comment: I'm confused now, sorry, I didn't get your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N = N*(N+1)/2.
Here is a solution in Python (I'm pretty sure I already answered that question but I can't find it):

```
def diag(i, j, N):
    if i+j < N:
        return (i+j)*(i+j+1)/2 + i + 1
    else:
        return N*N - diag(N-i-1, N-j-1, N) + 1
```

Then:

```
>>> [[diag(i,j, N) for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
[[1, 3, 6, 10, 15],
 [2, 5, 9, 14, 19],
 [4, 8, 13, 18, 22],
 [7, 12, 17, 21, 24],
 [11, 16, 20, 23, 25]]
```

Some explanations,

1. The cell in coordinate i,j lays in the diagonal i+j
2. The cell is in the upper half if i+j < N
3. Therefore, according to the remark, the first entry of the diagonal is (i+j)*(i+j+1)/2 + 1
4. hence the formula for upper half cells
5. for lower half cells, I just symmetrize the coordinate.

Comment: Thanks, your r a life saver :)

Comment: @hivert Can u pls give little exmplanation for this ?